# commutativity of non-scalar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:**

Prove that the commutativity on the set of non-scalar $2\times2$ matrices is an equivalence relation. (That is, for all A; B; and
C; if AB = BA and BC = CB then AC = CA:)

For commutativity to be equivalence relation, we have to it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. The first two properties are obvious. Any help on how to prove the third property?

Comment: What do you mean by non-scalar? Did you want to say _nonsingular_ (=invertible)? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix

Comment: I mean by scalar matrix a matrix that is a constant multiple of the identity matrix

Comment: @Martin, it's not true under that interpretation because $I$ is nonsingular and commutes with everything, but not everything commutes.

Comment: @Zi2018Alpha, I think the critical property is that a $2\times 2$ matrix has two different eigenvalues iff it is not a multiple of $I$. Is that hint enough? (You can work in $\mathbb C$ establishing your identity even if you're only interested in real matrices at the end of the day).

Comment: Henning describes the major case. I think that the other case of commuting 2x2-matrices with repeated eigenvalues needs its own treatment, but is easier in a way.

Comment: Yes, I missed the case of things that are $\pmatrix{a&b\\0&a}$ for some $b\ne 0$ in an appropriate basis.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, what you guys mean is to consider the two cases: First case: where $B=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_{1}  &0 \\ 
 0& \lambda_{2} 
\end{pmatrix}$ and in this case A and C have to diagonal matrices, and sure enough diagonal matrices commute with each other. Second case: where $B=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda  &1 \\ 
 0& \lambda 
\end{pmatrix}$ and in this case too, I can find that A and C commute with each other. Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is a write-up of the comments adding some thoughts that came to my mind:*

1. The first step is to show that $A$ and $B$ commute iff $S^{-1}AS$ and $S^{-1}BS$ commute. Therefore it follows that for the proof of transitivity, i.e. that we have $A$, $B$ and $C$ with $A$ and $B$ commuting and $B$ and $C$ commuting, we can assume that $B$ is in Jordan normal form. Now because we look at two cases: 2./3. (since $B$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity.
2. The matrix $B$ is a diagonal matrix with two distinct eigenvalues. In this case, as the OP already remarked it follows that also $A$ and $C$ are diagonal matrices and hence they commute.
3. The matrix $B$ consists of one Jordan block to a single eigenvalue. In this case, both $A$ and $C$ also have to be Jordan blocks with a single eigenvalue and one checks by direct computation that these commute.